# iOS: Trigger "swipe-to-delete" manually instead of a user interaction

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I have an UITableView with multiple UITableViewCells. I implemented the following delegate methods to allow the user the "swipe-to-delete" functionallity.

```
UITableView -> canEditRowAtIndexPath
UITableView -> commitEditingStyle
```

It basically looks like this now:
[image: current status]

But now i want to trigger the "swipe-gesture" manually from my code. I tryed to implement UITableView -> didSelectRowAtIndexPath and in there i was using cell.setEditing (true, animated: true). But it does not work. Any ideas on how i can do that?

Here is my current code:

```
var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath (indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
cell.setEditing (true, animated: true)
```

Thanks!